# Microsoft Word: add style to gallery from VBA code

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, styles

I import an HTML document into Microsoft Word for further processing. Some paragraphs in my HTML document are formatted with a class from the linked CSS like this:

```html
<p class="section_title">Section title</p>
```

The problem is that all the styles of the `<p>` tag used in the document are not shown in the Style Gallery by default and I need to add them manually using the Styles pane:

[image: Add Word style to Gallery]

Is there a way to automate this work with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `QuickStyle` property to True:

```vb
ActiveDocument.Styles("my style name").QuickStyle = True
```

In some situations (I guess it's the same feature/limitation as when assigned by hand), I couldn't see the style appear in the Style Gallery, but assigning the style to one character or paragraph helped. Here, applied to the current selection:

```vb
Selection.Style = "my style name"
```

Tested with Office 365.

NB: I have no idea how to remove the style from the gallery.